# Making Google Sheets work like a database

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to get Google Sheets to function like a Database, where sheets can "talk" back and forth to one another. Basically, a column on one sheet can auto-populate another column on a different sheet, and vice versa. HOWEVER, the other criterion is that the columns aren't necessarily in the same location on each sheet. In addition, there are many individual cells that merely have to talk back and forth to another, so it can't just be whole columns sharing information back and forth.

It's a little hard to explain, so I've attached the Sheet in question: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12MFlAqZGQsW6wxwSUyNaYJoFD3_Kt5uK7g88Tj_fAms/edit?usp=sharing
   Dummy information has been entered into the columns on each sheet to show where the information should be flowing. 
   There are quite a few picklists in the Sheet, and those would still have to be able to function.

There is another discussion which touches upon this process: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/OrObv5ZAmIs/-eNw5g5TGjUJ
   The issues with the above solution is that I don't need the other sheets to be hidden, and I have four sheets, most likely seven when the Sheet is completely finished.

It's a complicated Sheet that has to be as user-friendly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do this most often with the importrange function.  If you need to reorder columns in the second sheet you can specify a single column as you range and place it in any column you need in the new sheet.  Using multiple import range formulas in successive columns you can then reorder  your data set.  This approach is dynamic so any time your original data changes, the associated sheet updates as well.
If you only want to update the second sheet at certain times or on command you can do this with a script and a time trigger or a button object placed somewhere on the first sheet that is associated with the script.  The script would read the data from the originating sheet and the write it back to the second sheet in any order you wish.